# Set up simple HTTP server with PUT method

Tags: ubuntu, http, upload

I work on developing an internal testing document, and I'm running it through it's paces and one of the tests requires an HTTP PUT to upload a file.  I've looked around and tried a couple things online, but it appears that getting HTTP PUT to work is not a trivial thing.

I have an Amazon EC2 web server running Ubuntu 12 with Apache that I use as a sandbox that is set up to accept all the required traffic, but I cannot  get PUT to work. Any help, suggestions or direction to look would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what server are you using? Apache? Nginx? Something else?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Apache. I'll add that to the main post.

Comment: By default apache does not limit http methods you can use on requests and PUT should work without any additional configurations. How do you know the problem is related to PUT?

Comment: can you check if you have something like this enabled in your configuration? http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Securing_Apache#Disabling_PUT_and_DELETE

Comment: @Bnlf 405 Method Not Allowed